# Getting "multiple types were found that match the controller" error when submitting a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have came across this error and I solved it by using the overload of MapRoute that accepts a string array of namespaces. I had this issue mostly with hyperlinks. But now I have this issue when submitting a form. I call BeginForm() like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMotorcycle", "Motorcycle", FormMethod.Get))
```

But I have two Motorcycle controllers, I assume I have to specify a namespace. If I am correctly, how can I do that.

My motorcycle controllers are in:

appName.Controllers.Search
appName.Controllers.add

and that's what is reported to me when the error occurs.

Comment: Have you thought about using [areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas)?

Comment: If you using areas, the `BeginForm` should adding area name in `routeValues` parameter like this: `@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMotorcycle", "Motorcycle", new { area = "AreaName" }, FormMethod.Get, null))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Routing, and keeping the controllers in separate namespaces. MapRoute lets you specify which namespace corresponds to a route.

Example

Given this controllers:

```
 namespace CustomControllerFactory.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return new ContentResult("Controllers");
    }
}
}





 namespace CustomControllerFactory.ServiceControllers
 {
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return new ContentResult("ServiceControllers");
    }
   }
 }
```

and add the following routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Services",
       "Services/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "CustomControllerFactory.ServiceControllers" } // Namespace
    );


    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "CustomControllerFactory.Controllers"} // Namespace
    );
```

You should expect the following responses

/Services/Home - ServiceControllers

and 
/Home - Controller